# Chat room creation missing a lot of sites

Tags: bug, chat

Not all stack exchange sites seem to be accessible in this select a site dialog box.  I couldn't create a room for with related site `meta.askubuntu.com` as I was trying to do.

[image]

Comment: It probably only shows a certain number of sites? I assume you tried "meta Ubuntu"?

Comment: yeah, but it's not because of a certain number it's because some sites aren't in whatever lookup collection is populating that dialog

Comment: Can confirm. Most sites don't get a meta option.

Comment: Related: [Why can only some child meta sites host chat rooms? Is there any way to bypass this restriction?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325096) and [Which per-site-metas are offered in the chat-room creation dialogue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278334)