# Why can only some child meta sites host chat rooms? Is there any way to bypass this restriction?

Tags: support, bug, chat

[image]

When I try to create a new [Chat Stack Exchange](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) room from [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new), and type "meta" in the "select a site" box, I see only 8 child meta sites. Any specific reason for this?

**Update:**

I just noted [Which per-site-metas are offered in the chat-room creation dialogue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278334/which-per-site-metas-are-offered-in-the-chat-room-creation-dialogue) (pointed out by [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325096/why-can-only-some-child-meta-sites-host-chat-rooms#comment1061502_325096)). The conclusion of the experiment there was:

> 1. This experiment suggests that only the meta sites, for which at least
>      one room already exists, are offered.
> 2. ...the distinction between beta sites and graduated sites is not sufficient to explain this.

So, if I'm reading it correctly, it is currently *impossible* to create a room hosted on those child metas which do not already have an existing meta room (smells like a bug!)? Or is there a way to bypass this restriction somehow?

I can think of several legitimate reasons as to why a site may choose to keep their main chat rooms and meta chat rooms separate. Killing off that freedom of choice, and that too *non-uniformly*, isn't a good idea. If this really is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) rather than [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) (for a good cause), then it should be fixed!

Comment: Spitballing, I wonder if its cause they're older sites, but mathematics educators dosen't fit that...

Comment: I too suspected that initially, but in that case, even [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) should have been included as it was one of the [trilogy sites](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/31/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/). Moreover, yeah, [matheducators.se] certainly shouldn't have been there, by that logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which per-site-metas are offered in the chat-room creation dialogue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278334/which-per-site-metas-are-offered-in-the-chat-room-creation-dialogue)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for the reference. Given that that question wasn't a [tag:bug] report, and didn't receive any answer I'd refrain from marking this as a duplicate myself. However, if the community wishes to mark it as duplicate they're free to do so. If this really is a bug and not [tag:status-bydesign] SE really should fix it. I can think of several reasons to keep main chats and meta chats separate. I've also updated my question a bit, just in case anyone knows how to bypass this restriction given the current state of things.

Comment: OK, closed the other way around since there's answer here now explaining what's going on. (Well, in a sense)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just created [this room, parented to Ask Different Meta](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/90915/test-room?tab=general#) by intercepting the POST call made when creating a room as normal, just changing the `host` parameter at the end, and resubmit the call via curl. Note that I've redacted my `fkey` for security reasons, and there is a `&noDupeCheck=true&noDupeCheck=false` parameter of which I'm not sure how that is supposed to work, but it will skip the 'duplicate chatroom dialog' you sometimes get when creating a room. If it's not present in your original call, you should probably add it.

`curl 'https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/save' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Referer: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/save' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: [redacted]' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' --data 'fkey=[redacted]defaultAccess=read-write&name=Test+room&description=Test+room&host=apple.meta.stackexchange.com&tags=&noDupeCheck=true&noDupeCheck=false'`

The response should be something like

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/rooms/info/90923/test-room?tab=general">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

---

[image]

Similarly, it should be possible to intercept the 'save' call when changing a room's name or description, and manually changing the `host` parameter. I'm now wondering what would happen if you choose a non-existing site there ...

Comment: And now it appears in the list! So it means the list showing only meta sites **that already have associated chat rooms**. Heh.

Comment: Yep, and if we're diligent enough we can make this [bug] not reproducible anymore ...

Comment: Associate all dem rums! :P

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I'll let [Dr. Malcom respond](https://tenor.com/vYmp.gif). I don't see any great reason to have meta chat rooms with the exception of chat hanging off of this site. Do we really need a [third place](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/29/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/) for our second places?

Comment: By the way, is it possible to change the host of a room from main to meta (for mods)? I'm trying to rehome a QCSE main chat to QCSE meta.

Comment: The same trick should do the ... eh ... trick.

Comment: Wow. This is interesting. Would you mind adding this to the [unofficial documentation](https://github.com/jbis9051/JamesSOBot/blob/master/docs/CHAT_API.md)?

Comment: @JBis I'm on a break right now and I'll probably forget about it once I get home. I would do some more testing before adding a hack like this to *any* kind of documentation, but feel free to add a link to here or summary yourself.